# Reading Tab Delimited Data in to R

Tags: r, csv, import-from-csv

I am trying to read a large tab delimited file in to R.

First I tried this:

```
data <- read.table("data.csv", sep="\t")
```

But it is reading some of the numeric variables in as factors

So I tried to read in the data based on what type I want each variable to be like this:

```
data <- read.table("data.csv", sep="\t", colClasses=c("character","numeric","numeric","character","boolean","numeric"))
```

But when I try this it gives me an error:

> Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
>     scan() expected 'a real', got '"4"'

I think it might be that there are quotes around some of the numeric values in the original raw file, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without seeing your data, you have one of a few things:  you don't have all tabs separating the data; there are embeded tabs in single observations; or a litnay of others.

The way you can sort this out is to set `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` then use your first line.

Check out `str(data)` and try to figure out which rows are the culprits.  The reason some of the numeric values are reading as factors is because there is something in that column that R is interpreting as a character and so it coerces the whole column to character. It usually takes some digging but the problem is almost surely with your input file.

This is a common data munging issue, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response. That helps but instead of importing the variables I want to import as numeric, it imports them as characters. When I try to convert it to a numeric variable, it gives me NA's for all the observations. I'll take a closer look at the data though to check out the suggestions you made

Comment: Oh, looking closer at your error you've got quoted four. "4" R has put an extra set of single quote around it ' " 4 " '. this means in your tsv file, your numbers are quoted and thus treated as char.  add quote='"' to your read.table line and see how that works for you.

Comment: The problem is definitely that in my raw data file the values are enclosed with quotation marks so it is reading the values as characters when they should be numeric. I tried the quote='"' you mentioned above but that does not fix the problem...The raw data file is also too big so I cannot remove the quotes in a text editor or excel without crashing the programs

Comment: If you're on Linux or Unix, you can use the command line tool sed.  `sed -i s/\"//g filename` which will remove all instances of `"`.  But that might not be what you want...

Comment: Yep, I was able to remove the quotes using the command line. Then I could read in the data and convert it correctly to numeric. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- paste("'",floor(runif(10,0,10)),"'",sep="")
x

 [1] "'7'" "'3'" "'0'" "'3'" "'9'" "'1'" "'4'" "'8'" "'5'" "'8'"

as.numeric(gsub("'", "",x))

 [1] 7 3 0 3 9 1 4 8 5 8
```